# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs.settings' in Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

For some reason i am not able to migrate file from one to another. I am working on a Django project from the book "Python crash course". CMD prompt message-
`(ll_env) C:\Users\visha\learning_log>python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs.settings'` this is in the command prompt.
I checked the settings file and i did include the 'learning_logs' with a comma in installed apps tuple.
Here is the code of the python ' settings' file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# default apps
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# my apps
'learning_logs',]
```

I had seen solutions where they had to only include the comma but i have invcluded it and still get the error in command prompt.
Project structure:

```
C:.
├───learning_log
│   └───__pycache__
├───learning_logs
│   ├───migrations
│   └───__pycache__
```

Comment: Can you show your project structure?

Comment: How do i share it ?

Comment: (ll_env) C:\Users\visha\learning_log> (note: this is a virtual env.) in learning_log i have these folders 1.learning_log 2.learning_logs 3.ll_env 4. db.sqlite3(shortcutfile) 5. manage.py

Comment: You can execute a `tree` command inside your project directory and paste it's output as a block of code in your question. Feel free to edit the question when you need to clarify it.

Comment: ive done it but i dont think you can properly understand the structure.

Comment: Please pass it as a code block in the future to make it readable. Please also include all the files, not only directories. I believe `tree /f` will output the filenames as well.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for anyone to help you, unless they've run into that error before and can guess at what happened. Can you add the entire traceback from your terminal (all the output from running the makemigrations command), instead of just the exception? Also, if you can post your project on GitHub and link to it we can probably help you.